# docker-compose.yml for elasticsearch 7.0.1 and kibana 7.0.1

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am using Docker Desktop with linux containers on Windows 10 and would like to launch the latest versions of the elasticsearch and kibana containers over a docker compose file.

Everything works fine when using some older version like 6.2.4.

This is the working docker-compose.yml file for 6.2.4.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
   container_name: elasticsearch
   ports:
    - "9200:9200"
   volumes:
    - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   networks:
    - docker-network

  kibana:
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
   container_name: kibana
   ports:
    - "5601:5601"
   depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
   networks:
    - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

I deleted all installed docker containers and adapted the docker-compose.yml file by changing 6.2.4 to 7.0.1.
By starting the new compose file everything looks fine, both the elasticsearch and kibana containers are started. But after a couple of seconds the elasticsearch container exits (the kibana container is running further). I restarted everything, attached a terminal to the elasticsearch container and saw the following error message:

```
...
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
...
```

What must be changed in the docker-compose.yml file to get elasticsearch 7.0.1 working?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Making a few changes worked for me -

- Add `cluster.initial_master_nodes` to the elasticsearch service in compose -

  ```
  environment:
    - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
  ```
- `vm.max_map_count` on the linux box kernel setting needs to be set to at least 262144 -

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
  ```

For development mode, you can use below settings as well -

```
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

Working compose file for me -

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200
```

For production mode, you must consider having multiple ES nodes/containers as suggested in the official documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

Comment: Thank you for the information. Elasticsearch and kibana 7.0.1 containers are running now, after adding the "cluster.initial_master_nodes" line to the environment. But kibana cannot access elasticsearch anymore. Here is the kibana error message: ```{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-03T08:49:43Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-03T08:49:43Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}```

Comment: Forgot to say that I did not set the "vm.max_map_count" parameter in the linux container. I am using docker desktop on Windows 10, how can this parameter be set?

Comment: `discovery.type=single-node` helped for me, running ES from `docker-compose` for my local development.