# Why elasticsearch docker image keeps on appearing and disappearing?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running into a weird situation :
today morning I configured a **docker-compose.yml file on ubuntu 16.04 everything was ok, later on I tried the same docker configuration on a different PC with ubuntu 16.04 it didn't work.**

The elasticsearch image appears and disappears, **ports 9200 and 5601 are not occupied**

**docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

[image]

**I tried to change the ports and add ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200/ nothing worked!!!**

```
[root@localhost ELK]# curl localhost:5601
Kibana server is not ready yet[root@localhost ELK]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the logs first. Only run the elasticsearch container without the `-d` option in `docker-compose` and see the logs.

Its most likely an issue with certain other parameters you'll need.

First do

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Also add `vm.max_map_count` setting to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it permanent.

Add ulimits and other few parameters to docker-compose

```
ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536

environment:
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
```

Check [How to use the official docker elasticsearch container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002643/how-to-use-the-official-docker-elasticsearch-container) and [docker-compose.yml for elasticsearch 7.0.1 and kibana 7.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956645/docker-compose-yml-for-elasticsearch-7-0-1-and-kibana-7-0-1) for more